# Is it possible to get any kind of unique identifier for the Infiniband switch that a particular Linux box is connected to?

Tags: linux, networking, redhat, infiniband

I am trying to identify which Infiniband NIC's are connected to which switches, in a manner that is very similar to [this question](https://serverfault.com/questions/495491/how-to-identify-nics-that-are-connected-to-the-same-switch-from-a-linux-box).

However, the solution proposed there is not working for Mellanox Infiniband switches, and I have not been able to find any alternatives.

Is there a standard way to query for an identifier for the Infiniband switch that a particular machine is connected to?

Answer (score 2):

The MLNX_EN for Linux or MTNIC Driver should be installed on your Linux Machine. Than use the 'ethtool' or 'mstflint' commands as follows:

> ethtool -i eth2
>           driver:      mlnx_en (MT_0DD0120009_CX3)   <--- This is the PSID
>           version:    2.1.6 (Feb 2014)
>           firmware-version: 2.30.8000 
>           bus-info: 0000:1a:00.0
>   mstflint:
>   1. Get the device location on the PCI bus:
>   lspci
>       ....... 
>       04:00.0 InfiniBand: Mellanox Technologies MT4099 [ConnectX-3 VPI FDR, IB (56Gb/s) and 40GigE; PCIe3.0 x8 8GT/s; RoHS R6].
>   2. Get the PSID of your product, enter: > mstflint -d 04:00.0 q
>       Image type:           FS2
>       FW Version:         2.30.8000
>       Device ID:            4099
>       Chip Revision:       A1
>       Description:     Node Port1 Port2 Sys image
>       GUIDs:            0002c90307e25050 0002c90307e25051
>       MACs:            0002c9e25750 0002c9e25751
>       VSD:            N/A
>       PSID:            MT_1090120019

Following Mellanox support page: http://www.mellanox.com/page/firmware_HCA_FW_identification

Comment: While I will certainly try this, it is better to put the exact commands into the answer that you think will resolve the question.

Comment: sure :-) good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can use the `ibnetdiscover` tools from the `infiniband-diags` package. It prints out the InfiniBand network topology, including the switches and which host port is connected to which switch port.

Answer (score 0):

You are asking about **infiniband**, so any **ethernet**-related tool (as described in the other question that you link to or in one of the answers here) is irrelevant.

The ID of the switch in infiniband is its GUID.

Run `ibhosts` to get the list of all the HCAs that you have in your subnet.
Run `ibswitches` to get the list of all the switches that you have in your subnet.

Now, if you want to get the complete topology, run `ibnetdiscover`, as suggested by @haggai_e.

If you question is more specific, like what is the switch GUID that is connected to the 1st port of this NIC (called "HCA" in infiniband) on this particular Linux box, you can directly query this switch with `smpquery` tool.

Run it as follows: `smpquery -D NodeInfo 0,1`

Run `smpquery -h` for more usage info.